# Android : Listview of text and Image and the weird scrolling behaviour

Tags: android, android-layout, exception, android-listview

In my application I need to create two lists each with different data . I have designed the UI like adding two listviews one after another in a TableLayout within a LinearLayout. I have stored the data in  two String arrays and used arrayadapter to populate into the listview.My listview contain a textview and an image.The problem is
1.There is no error shown in the code but the list is getting populated in weird manner. 1st list item is shown, 2nd,3rd,4th list item not shown and 5th is shown 6th not shown, from 7th its fine. When i scroll up, the list is showing all the list items.
2.each list should have its own scrolling control. like if I scroll List "A" ,it should only be scrolled not the  List"B" and vice versa. I have attached the code here . Thanks in advance.

mainscreen.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_LinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/request_Table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/request_Row1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/request_TextView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="REQUESTS"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/widget163"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/request_Row2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/gray"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/request_ListView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/offered_Table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/offered_Row1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/offered_TextView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="OFFERED"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/offered_Row2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/offered_ListView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/gray"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:smoothScrollbar="true" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

mainscreen.java

```
   public class MainMenu extends Activity  {

     RequestAdapter mRequestAdapter;
     ListView mListView_req ;
    public class RequestData {
        int icon;
        String list_text;

        public RequestData( String mText) {
            super();
            //this.icon=image;
            this.list_text=mText;
        }

    }
    private RequestData[] getListItems(){
        Resources mRes = getResources();
        String[] sListItems= mRes.getStringArray(R.array.request_list);
        int listsize = sListItems.length;
        RequestData[] obj = new RequestData[listsize];
        int size = obj.length;
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
            obj[i] = new RequestData(sListItems[i]);
        }
        return obj;     
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu_screen);
        mListView_req= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.request_ListView) ;
        mRequestAdapter = new RequestAdapter(this,R.layout.listitem, getListItems());
          mListView_req.setAdapter(mRequestAdapter);


    }
    class RequestAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

        private RequestData rList[]= null;
        Context context;

        public RequestAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                RequestData[] data) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, data);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.rList= data;
        }

        @Override
        public RequestData getItem(int position){

            return rList[position];
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row= convertView;
            if (row== null){
                row = getLayoyutinflater().inflate(R.layout.listitem,null);
            }
            else {
                RequestData items = getItem(pos);
                TextView text= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.List_Text);
                if(text!= null){
                    text.setText(items.list_text);
            }

        }
            return row;


        }
```

listitem.xml :

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="150dp">    
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="100dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" 
        android:id="@+id/text"/>
    <ImageView> 
        android:layout_width="40dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow" 
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: we need to see your list population code

Comment: I already shared the class file . and I have used the arrayadapter only not any custom adapter.

Comment: if you want a list item with text + image, you need to write a custom adapter

Comment: @Candy : so here the problem I face is because I used array adapter instead of a custom adapter ?

Comment: @Candy: Thanks for your comment .Based on your guideline i have changed my adapter to customAdapter.but now , am not gettg any errors but list not been populated.

Comment: Have you checked that your getListItems() is returning an array whose length is higher than 0? If it is, also check if getView() method is called at all or not?

Comment: @dalandroid:Yeah I have checked it , and now its populating but in weird manner. I have edited the question , please check it out and help me out in figuring where am I wrong.